# Rails Devise - how to open access to the site root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a Rails app that acts as a backend for an iOS app. It was developed by a third party, and I've never used Rails, so trying to learn as I go here. I want to make the app web-accessible for users, with a homepage front-end for giving prospective users some info about the app.

Sounds easy enough, but the app is using Devise for user authentication and when I hit the site root I get the following error message:

```
You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
```

In the routes.rb file I have the following:

```
root :to => "visitors#index"
devise_for :users
resources :users
```

In my visitors controller I added a before_filter to try to open up the site index:

```
class VisitorsController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:index]
end
```

but this made no difference. Is there something obvious I'm missing here, or some concept that I'm not grasping? Basically I want a user to hit the site homepage, then click on a 'Login' link, after which they'll have access to the rest of the site.

EDIT:

My ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  respond_to :html, :json

  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.request.format == 'application/json'}
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post your `ApplicationController`?

Comment: Is the app running in `production` or `development`? If `production`, code might be cached and changes may not be visible until a restart of the app server.

Comment: @D-side: It's running on my development machine, but I've been restarting the server after every change just to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone else has the same problem - the culprit was the following line in application_controller.rb:

```
acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
```

It's part of the simple_token_authentication Gem (https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication)

To fix enable anonymous access to the root page, I changed it to the following:

```
acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, :except => [:index]
```

Answer (score 1):

From `Devise's` [how to guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-authentication-for-all-pages) which seems to describe your example. You can create two roots in your `routes.rb` file. One for authenticated user's and one for non-authenticated users:

```
authenticated :user do
  root :to => 'visitors#some_action', :as => :authenticated_root
end

root :to => 'visitors#index'
```

However, please post your `ApplicationController` because your example code ***should*** work, the issue may be there.

Comment: I tried this, but no change. I've added my ApplicationController above.

Comment: @aritchie Could you try removing your `except` and adding `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, :only => :index`

Comment: no change, still getting the error. In the terminal where I'm running the site with 'rails s' I get the message: "Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-24 12:36:02 +0000
Processing by VisitorsController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0ms"